# Reconcile XML Updates

Tags: .net, xml, concurrency, merge

I have an set XML files that store simple bits of data. In each case the data in the files is structured differently, storing different types of data, but always simple. There is a file on the server, which can either be downloaded and updated offline or updated online. So here's the problem: What happens if while a user has a file offline for updating the file is updated and now they want to upload their changes to the server? Is there a way to handle this preferably in .Net? It is also worth nothing that the changes are not frequent. In most cases a new file would be created for major changes; we're just talking about minor update to older files and I want to plan for an update collision if it happens.

For example:

Original File:

`[person]
  [name]Bob[/name]
  [address]123 Street[/address]
  [phone]123-456-7890[/phone]
[/person]`

Changes Made Offline:

`[person]
  [name]Bob[/name]
  [address]124 Street[/address]
  [phone]123-456-7890[/phone]
[/person]`

Changes Made Online:

`[person]
  [name]Bob[/name]
  [address]123 Street[/address]
  [phone]124-456-7890[/phone]
[/person]`

Ideal Result:

`[person]
  [name]Bob[/name]
  [address]124 Street[/address]
  [phone]124-456-7890[/phone]
[/person]`

On some occasions there will be new elements to be merged in to the base file. I have the option to structure the XML files however I want, so I can add in an attribute as some sort of element ID if that would help, but I'd prefer not to have to do that.

Thanks for your help. If there are other suggestions on how to manage this scenario that don't involve XML I'm open to those ideas as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that adding a unique identifier (i.e. a GUID) to each snippet may be the simplest way to quickly and accurately merge the documents.  If these files are programmaticaly edited, you can create a GUID on the server or offline client for new snippests and not need to worry about collisions.  Such a system will be easier to debug and maintain than a system that attempts to identify whether a snippet has changed or is new.

I'm not aware of any built in libraries that can identify large scale changes to text.  You might could hook into a subversion or other source control library that has code for determining how text has changed but I think that would be overly complicated for what is required.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this idea is the fact that in the sample above it would more than double the size of the file, which isn't great for storage or manipulation, especially for a feature that may never be used.

Comment: Is file size a constraint?  If so you could always get a zip library and zip the xml file.  Mostly I see this as a time vs effort trade-off.  You might could do a fancier solution, but if this is going to be a little used feature, is it really worth more of your time than it takes to bang out a simple, effective solution?  This is all my own opinion of course; I don't know your circumstances, but from the information given, there just doesn't seem to be much point in investing a lot of time in something like this.  Best of luck, whatever you decide though.

Comment: File size isn't a constraint as much as there will be thousands of these little buggers, and size adds up. I'm already ZIPping them for transmission and storage. I think I'll just write my own 'GUID' generator that will keep the keys short and use the method you suggest. If I'm only dealing with a few dozen records per file a collision of IDs shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: I was also thinking that a short identifier compared with a XPath would pretty much eliminate an ID collision.

Comment: That also works.  The identifier doesn't need to be a guid, I just suggested them because they're unique and easy to generate, but any unique identifer will do.

Comment: I've completed my code according to your suggestion and it works great. I ended up using XDocument and associates to get the job done and it works quite quickly I might add. Thanks for your help.